# gson: convert /Date(1341348517698+0200)/ to Calendar

Tags: android, json, calendar, gson

I'm trying to deserialize a DateTime (C#) which comes as JSON (StartDate=/Date(1341348517698+0200)/) to an Android Calendar object using gson...

I already tried the following without success:

```
ObjectWithCalender cal = gson.fromJson(jsonWithDate, ObjectWithCalender.class);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a custom deserializer for Date. e.g. create this class:

```
public class DotNetDateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {
   @Override
   public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typfOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
      // this is the place where you convert .NET timestamp into Java Date object
   } 
}
```

Then before converting a JSON string into POJO:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DotNetDateDeserializer());
Gson gson = builder.create();
gson.fromJson(jsonString, Class);
```

Comment: I used the Java 'Date.class' as an example, but you can replace it with 'Calendar.class'.

Answer (score 1):

use unix timestamp instead of datetime, datetime is ambiguous struct

Comment: How would I get a Calendar from a unix timestamp? Is that built-in or would I have to write a custom deserializer?

Comment: before using in calendar convert to datetime, but in transport use numeric it's unchangeable

Answer (score 1):

```java
/**
 * The Class CalendarFromTimestampJsonDeserializer.
 */
    public class CalendarFromTimestampJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Calendar>{

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer#deserialize(com.google.gson.JsonElement, java.lang.reflect.Type, com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext)
         */
        public Calendar deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            long timestamp = json.getAsLong();
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
            return calendar;
        }
    }
```

And then

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
            builder.registerTypeAdapter(Calendar.class, new CalendarFromTimestampJsonDeserializer());
            Gson gson = builder.create();
```

In the case of a list

```
List<ObjectWithCalendar> objList = gson.fromJson(objectJsonArray.toString(), new TypeToken<List<ObjectWithCalendar>>(){}.getType());
```

or else an object

```
ObjectWithCalendar obj = gson.fromJson(objectJson.toString(), ObjectWithCalendar.class);
```